# Painting on top of clear topcoat

Tags: paint

I'm going to repaint a ceiling that has a faux finish and a clear topcoat on it. The faux finish is some kind of yellow smear and the topcoat a rather low sheen, I would say satin. Is it necessary to prime with something like INSL-X Stix because of the clear coat, or can I get away with using ceiling paint directly on top?

Comment: Harper gave great advise.  If after your test it is apparent that the old finish will not accept paint very well then i would recommend a good **Bonding** primer.

Comment: Hi @AlaskaMan - it's more useful to vote up a good answer (if you think Harper's is good, please give it a vote) and if you have further answers, please post as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

As for the paint compatibility, the standard advice is to either paint an innocuous area and try it, or do a [crosshatch test](https://www.defelsko.com/resources/finish-coatings-system-adhesion-and-test-methods).

The low sheen is caused by the paint being intentionally "bumpy". That tends to produce good binding to the next coat, so I would expect reasonable results.

The other reason we use primer is as a "barrier coat" to assure chemical compatibility (that the paints don't react to each other or fail to stick).  Again a paint or crosshatch test will reveal that.